# Query to retrieve messages from Skype conversation from SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, skype

I'm trying to get conversations from Skype messages but new versions of Skype changed the path of the database file and its structure to JSON.

I downloaded the "DB Browser for SQLite" to query the content of the database.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I'm posting a doubt with its solution, thanks

Comment: @PabloAlmaguer Tip for the next time you want to answer your own question (which is positively encouraged): at the very bottom of the _Ask a question_ page (under the "_Post Your Question_" button), there is a checkbox "_Answer your own question_". As [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) describes, clicking this will allow you to add the answer immediately, so that both are published at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

New path of Skype database file: `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\<Skype Name>.db`

Here's an example of a query to extract the message data from a JSON structure

```
select creator,
       compose_time,
       msg_content,
       original_arrival_time
  from (select json_extract(msg.nsp_data, '$.creator') as "creator",
              json_extract(msg.nsp_data, '$._serverMessages[0].composetime') as "compose_time",
              json_extract(msg.nsp_data, '$._serverMessages[0].content') as "msg_content",
              json_extract(msg.nsp_data, '$._serverMessages[0].originalarrivaltime') as "original_arrival_time"
        from messagesv12 msg)
 where 1=1
   --and strftime('%Y%m%d', compose_time) > strftime('%Y%m%d', date('now'), '-4 day')
   --and creator = ''
 order by compose_time;
```

You can read the documentation of json_extract() funcion in https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/